# Using deparse(substitute) for several strings

Tags: r, function

The combination of `deparse(substitute)` seems useful. However, how can I use this for several strings.
Working example:

```
print_name<-function(x){
x<-deparse(substitute(x))
print(x)
}
```

How can I make this work for something like this?

```
print_name<-function(x,...){
  x<-deparse(substitute(x))
  y<-deparse(substitute(...))
  print(x)
  print(y)
}

print_name(Peter,John,Alice)
```

The above almost works except it stops at(on?) John. How can I make it work for all names. That is print Peter,John,Alice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
print_name<-function(x,...){
  x<-deparse(substitute(x))
  y<-sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)
  print(x)
  print(y)
}

print_name(Peter,John,Alice)
# [1] "Peter"
# [1] "John"  "Alice"
```

If we do `substitute(...())` we will get a list-like object of all the symbols, and we just sapply over them to turn each of them into a character value

Comment: Is it possible to get Alice print(ed) on a new line?

Comment: Well, `print()` by default will put as many values as it can on a line. Is this a question about printing? What is your actual use case? What exactly did you expect `y` to contain?

Comment: I'm trying to do some manipulations that can only work if these names are printed each on their own line. Got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't really answer what type of object you expect `y` to be. Do you expect each value to still be preceded with the `"[1]"` like `print()` will do by default? Can't you just do `print(y[1]); print(y[2]);`? If you just need to print each value on it's own line, why are you doing something different with the first value? It would be easier if you specific the exact output that you are after in your question. Also indicate what should happen if a different number of arguments are passed in.

Comment: It worked. This was a sample question but it helped me solve the problem.